# Gradient boosting target construction (binned classifier)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, modeling, gradient-descent, boosting

Question about engineering the target variable for a gradient boosted classifier algorithm...

The raw target variable is "% change in revenue"

You have decided to convert this continuous value into bins, create a classified Y/target.

You have 3 alternatives:

1. Predict 1 of 3 bins: growth, same, decline
2. Predict 1 of 7 bins: -20%+, -20% to -10%, -10% to -2%, -2% to 2%, 2% to 10%, 10% to 20%, 20%+ | After predicting, group up the bins into growth, same, decline, in other words, combine them in your confusion matrix to determine metrics for 3 groups
3. Same as #2, except with 15 bins, which are predicted then grouped into growth, same, decline

Is there a general "best practice" here, or is it going to completely depend on your data?